# Consequences of deactivating and activating Publishing feature at site collection level and site level

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, publishing

Go to Site Settings -> under Site Administration, select "Content and Structure". At the first page there is a list of the files with a "view" in the toolbar on the right section. Drop this down and choose "Checked out to me". Navigate to the folder where the files you wish to check in are located.

End users are unable to see their personal view. When they select the view "Checked out to me" it circles back to default view only. To get this view, i want to disable and enable publishing features at site collection level and site level. By doing it will it have any impact for end users who are working on any site?

Answer (score 0):

If you disable Publishing feature at site level and site collection level, any user data or customizations associated with this feature might be lost. In addition, any active features and apps that depend on this feature might fail to function, for example, Pages library, navigation, etc.

Some articles for your reference:
[SharePoint Tips and Tricks: The Publishing Feature](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2014/08/07/the-publishing-feature.aspx)

[Benefits of enabling "SharePoint server Publishing " site feature inside my sub site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/147239/benefits-of-enabling-sharepoint-server-publishing-site-feature-inside-my-sub)

[What happens when I enable SharePoint Server Publishing & SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature inside Team Site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214425/what-happens-when-i-enable-sharepoint-server-publishing-sharepoint-server-publ)